# Hibernate - Unable to read the values from table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Unable to read the data from table through hibernate.**But same SQL working in TOAD**.

SQL:

```
SELECT distinct pub.asdfg, pub.list, pub.prod, pub.prod_desc  FROM  Pubsh pub  WHERE pub.prod in ('123456')
```

Table def :

```
CREATE TABLE "PUBSH"
(
   KEY decimal(22) NOT NULL,
   PROD varchar2(54) NOT NULL,
   PRODKEY decimal(22),
   PROD_DESC varchar2(360),
   PARTEY decimal(22) NOT NULL,
   LIST_TYPE varchar2(90),
   PUBLISH_DATE date,
   PUBSH_PERIOD varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
   PL_KEY decimal(22),
   LIST varchar2(750),
   EL_KEY decimal(22),
   NEL varchar2(60) }
```

Error in console :

```
    org.hibernate.SQL - SELECT distinct pub.nel, pub.list, pub.prod, pub.prod_desc  FROM  PUBSH WHERE pub.prod in ('12345')
        org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
             org.hibernate.type.StringType - could not read column value from result set; Invalid column name
        org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
        org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - could not execute query [SELECT distinct pub.nel, pub.list, pub.prodr, pub.desc  FROM  PUBSH WHERE pub.prod in ('12345')]
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3711)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2806)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
            at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getString(Unknown Source)
            at org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(StringType.java:18)
            at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
            at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:189)
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(CustomLoader.java:474)
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(CustomLoader.java:420)
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:317)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
```

DAO method to execute Hibernate :

```
public List<SearchResult> find(final String Query1) {  
       return (List<SearchResult>)getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback(){
         public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException{
           Query query1 =  session.createSQLQuery(channelQuery1)
                                   .addScalar("nel",Hibernate.STRING)
                                   .addScalar("price",Hibernate.STRING)
                                   .addScalar("prodr",Hibernate.STRING)
                                   .addScalar("prodcr",Hibernate.STRING)
                                   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SearchResult.class));

               return query1.list();
             }
```

Please advise why i'm getting invalid column name error while accessing the through hibernate ?

Comment: what is the value of Query1? also activate sql query log and see the query that hibernate is executing

Comment: Query1 didn't execute ,i was getting error while executing hibernate and sql log updated in the question section.

Comment: Please do not remove content from your question in this manner, as it will make the answer seem irrelevant. I don't see anything remotely 'confidential' there. When you posted, you agreed to a CC-WIKI license for the content.

Comment: No , please delete the question.I have posted actual table and field list.Could you consider the request and delete the question.

Comment: @user2444474 there isn't any confident information on your question that can be used by another person

Comment: @user2444474 btw if you are worried about what you have posted, next time try to solve it by yourself... we all spend valuable time on these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a SQL query but the scalar properties are different than the one declared in the table:

```
.addScalar("prodNbr",Hibernate.STRING)
.addScalar("prodDescr",Hibernate.STRING)
```

these properties are declared `PROD_NBR` and `PROD_DESC` in the table, so change the code to

```
.addScalar("CHANNEL",Hibernate.STRING)
.addScalar("PRICELIST",Hibernate.STRING)
.addScalar("PROD_NBR",Hibernate.STRING)
.addScalar("PROD_DESC",Hibernate.STRING)
```